# Unity3d FB.canvas.pay alternative for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, payment

After adding FB.canvas.pay method in Unity3d using Facebook SDK, I found this debug log, "Pay method only works with Facebook Canvas.  Does nothing in the Unity Editor, iOS or Android".

Is there any way around to make the Facebook payment work on android (and iOS)?

I am assuming there is a way to do that using the Graph Api's "payment" node. If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no workaround for this on Android and iOS as payments is ONLY available on Canvas.

The "payment" node that you are referencing doesn't support traditional POST methods that you could use on other nodes of the Graph API.